# How to push new column into array using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using an external library to build a Taskboard and what I want to achieve is to add a new column when clicking and add column button. I am struggling with adding the column, I have the newly created column but it doesn't get added to the array. What am I doing wrong and how can I insert the newly created column? Here is my code:

```
  onAddColumn = () => {
    const newColumn: TaskBoardColumnModel = {
      id: this.state.columnsData.length + 1,
      title: 'New Column',
      status: 'new',
      edit: true,
    };

    console.log(this.state.columnsData);

    this.setState({
      columsData: newColumn,
    });
    console.log(this.state.columsData);
  };
}
```

Comment: `columsData` vs `columnsData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is the way you update your state. This is what you have:

```js
this.setState({
      columsData: newColumn,
    });
```

This piece of code will set the state to `columsData: newColumn`, which is wrong for a few reasons:

- columsData should be columnsData
- Your piece of code will remove all the other columns and replace it with only one. Which will fail the code because columnsData will become an object and not an array

Here is what it should be:

```js
this.setState({
      columnsData: [...this.state.columnsData, newColumn],
    });
```

This will keep your current state, and add the new column to your existing list.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need `...this.state,` : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: @BenStephens Is this a new feature, or only for class based components? The last time I used these in function components I remember the need for this.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't work like that for functional components' state updates, but there you can have multiple state variables (if you want them). I don't use class components so not sure when it was added, but it was there in 17: https://17.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: @BenStephens See the note here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates. It's a function component thing it seems, so code can be simplified indeed

Comment: In that case, your second bullet point "You are overwriting the whole state with only your columns" seems like it's probably wrong to me.

Comment: @BenStephens You're right, updated

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `columsData`. Additionally `columnsData` should be an array so you probably need to set the new state to the old one plus the new column.

e.g. something like:

```
this.setState({
    columnsData: [...this.state.columnsData, newColumn],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo in your code. The property you are updating in `setState` is `columsData` instead of `columnsData`. Due to this typo, the new column is not getting added to the array correctly. To fix this, you need to update the `setState` call to use the correct property name `columnsData`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
onAddColumn = () => {
  const newColumn: TaskBoardColumnModel = {
    id: this.state.columnsData.length + 1,
    title: 'New Column',
    status: 'new',
    edit: true,
  };

  console.log(this.state.columnsData);

  this.setState({
    columnsData: [...this.state.columnsData, newColumn],
  });

  console.log(this.state.columnsData);
};
```

In the `setState` call, we use the spread operator (`...`) to create a new array that includes all the existing columns in `this.state.columnsData`, and then we add the `newColumn` to the end of the new array.

By doing this, the new column will be correctly added to the `columnsData` array when you click the "Add Column" button.